# How to calculate sum of a metric for rest of the month, quarter and year daily in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table with data starting from Jan 1, 2021 to current date.

I am calculating the MTD, QTD, YTD values against each date using these queries

MTD- "sum(METRIC) over ( partition by segment_grp, trunc(activity_date,'MM') order by activity_date range between activity_date-trunc(activity_date,'MM') preceding and 0 following) MTD_METRIC"

QTD- "sum(METRIC) over ( partition by segment_grp, trunc(activity_date,'Q') order by activity_date range between activity_date-trunc(activity_date,'Q') preceding and 0 following) QTD_METRIC"

YTD- "sum(METRIC) over ( partition by segment_grp, trunc(activity_date,'YYYY') order by activity_date range between activity_date-trunc(activity_date,'YYYY') preceding and 0 following) YTD_METRIC"

I also want to calculate the rest of the month, rest of the quarter, rest of the year metric as well. How do I modify the above queries to do that?

Sample data for Nov 2021:
CREATE TABLE TEMP_SUMMARY
(
ACTIVITY_DATE   DATE,
SEGMENT_GRP     VARCHAR2(140 CHAR),
MONTH           VARCHAR2(6 CHAR),
YEAR            VARCHAR2(4 CHAR),
QUARTER         CHAR(2 CHAR),
METRIC          NUMBER,
MTD_METRIC      NUMBER,
QTD_METRIC      NUMBER,
YTD_METRIC      NUMBER,
ROM_METRIC      NUMBER,
ROQ_METRIC      NUMBER,
ROY_METRIC      NUMBER
)

insert into TEMP_SUMMARY (ACTIVITY_DATE,SEGMENT_GRP,MONTH,YEAR,QUARTER,METRIC,MTD_METRIC,QTD_METRIC,YTD_METRIC) values (to_date('01/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy'), 'ENT', '202111', '2021', 'Q4', 149, 149, 5219, 56396)

insert into TEMP_SUMMARY (ACTIVITY_DATE,SEGMENT_GRP,MONTH,YEAR,QUARTER,METRIC,MTD_METRIC,QTD_METRIC,YTD_METRIC) values (to_date('02/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy'), 'ENT', '202111', '2021', 'Q4', 382, 531, 5601, 56778)

Nov 1-
Rest of the month: sum(Nov 2 to 30 Metric)
Rest of the quarter: sum(Nov 2 to 30 Metric, Dec Meric)
Rest of the year: sum(Nov 2 to 30 Metric, Dec Meric)

Nov 2-
Rest of the month: sum(Nov 3 to 30 Metric)
Rest of the quarter: sum(Nov 3 to 30 Metric, Dec Metric)
Rest of the year: sum(Nov 3 to 30 Metric, Dec Metric)

Thanks!

Comment: In the future, please include sample data as text not as images.  Include the table definition (you can't name a column "date" for example).  Ideally, include the sample data in the form of DML statements we can run (or create a link to something like dbfiddle where you've done that work).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want a simple analytic function

```
select sum( daily_count ) over (partition by month order by dt) mtd,
       sum( daily_count ) over (partition by quarter order by dt) qtd,
       sum( daily_count ) over (partition by year order by dt) ytd
  from your_table
```